# How to build Debian release like packages from an arbitary kernel source?

Tags: debian, kernel, packaging

I'd like to take an arbitrary kernel (say, 4.1.33), patch it with something (say, linux-vserver), and then build the sorts of packages Debian builds and distributes (including e.g. `linux-perf-4.1.33`). I don't insist on the resulting packages being DFSG-free.

I'm aware of `make deb-pkg`, but that doesn't build the perf package, or the other packages that result from the Debian `linux-tools` source package.

I understand `make-kpkg` is deprecated.

I'm familiar with https://wiki.debian.org/HowToRebuildAnOfficialDebianKernelPackage?action=recall&rev=108 (which had more specific instructions, albeit outdated ones, than https://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-official, where the current version of the wikipage points); however, these guides don't deal with the situation where I want to package a kernel that has never been released in Debian.

My top priority is obtaining a `linux-perf` package appropriate for my kernel; a `linux-kbuild` package would be nice but not essential.